# Loading an Ionic app inside a browser with a Mobile Shell

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Let say I have an app built with ionic and then I want to build a web app that will display like an iPhone shell and load the ionic app inside it so that it gives like a preview of the app running. It's like having a web page loading another web page isn't it? So using javascript to load another page would be a solution?

Thanks,

Comment: Check this out https://ionicframework.com/pro

Comment: yeah I'm trying to figure out how they do it.